# How to track email send over smtp via code?

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I have an application which sends 2 to 3 Emails daily from a C# programm.

I am using my email provided by gmail.com like my email is `abc@xxxx.com` so I can logg in into gmail.com via `abc@xxxx.com`, (xxxx not gmail because I am using google mail provider).

So to send the Email I am passing SMTPUser name `abc@xxxx.com` and password of `abc@xxxx.com`. When I am sending the Email with other user of `@xxxx.com`, lets say `def@xxxx.com` to `xyz@gmail.com`.

Once I sent the Email (via C# program) I am trying to login after 2/3 hours into `abc@xxxx.com` via www.gmail.com , I have found the Email which I sent to `xyz@gmail.com` via c# program in SENT items of this account, even I have not found in SENT items of `def@xxxx.com`.

So my question is how to track such emails from the www.gmail.com account?

My question is to - when I am sent an email via c# program to xyz@gmail.com from abc@xxxx.com. after 2/3 hrs I am go to www.gmail.com loggedin with abc@xxxx.com but that sent email not found in sent items of xyz@gmail.com, similarly I logged in with def@xxxx.com and not found any email in sent items of def@xxxx.com.Where I can found that sent email in SENT ITMES Of whihc account?

```
public MailMessage msg;
SmtpClient objSMTP;
MessageStatus msgStatus;


objSMTP = new SmtpClient("x.x.x.x");
objSMTP.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@xxxx.com","pwd", true));
//objSMTP.EnableSsl = true;
MsgFrmID = "test@xxxx.com"

msg.From = "def@xxxx.com";

msg.To="xyz@gmail.com;"
msg.Subject = MsgSubject;
msg.Body = MsgData;
objSMTP.Send(msg);
```

Comment: i've read this twice now and am still not sure what the question is, or what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you asking how to track if your emails have been sent successfully (see un-lucky answer) or if they have been recieved (not possible in any reliable manner).

Comment: @user1666620- My question is to - when I am sent an email via c# program to xyz@gmail.com from abc@xxxx.com. after 2/3 hrs I am go to www.gmail.com loggedin with abc@xxxx.com but that sent email not found in sent items of xyz@gmail.com, similarly I logged in with def@xxxx.com and not found any email in sent items of def@xxxx.com.Where I can found that sent email in SENT ITMES Of whihc account?

Comment: are you sure your code is actually working correctly? what exception logging do you have in place? can you show your code?

Comment: @user1666620 - I have added my code in my question,please refer that.

Comment: @skiskd,if you send any mail over c# program by any mail id then that mail will not be available in sent items folder of that mail id,

Comment: @Guru - I want to have that email into sent item folder of that email id, Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @skiskd, no that is not at all possible, but instead add the same mail id to TO section so that you can have one copy if the email in your inbox rather than sent items,

Answer (score 2):

If your mail is not send successfully it definitely throws some exception. so that we can track this by enclosing it in a `try...catch` block as follows

```
        try
        {
            SmtpClient Smtp_Server = new SmtpClient();
            MailMessage e_mail = new MailMessage();
          //code here for mail message and client configuration
            Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail send successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("failed to send mail");
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way I know. +1 to you un-lucky